# Haskell name declaration rules

Tags: haskell, declaration

I'm teaching myself Haskell, and I've come across two implementations of a "flip" function that raise questions for me about name declaration.

These two do the same thing:

```
flip'' :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c  
flip'' f y x = f x y  

flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)  
flip' f = g  
    where g x y = f y x
```

The first example is as I would expect. In the second example, I'm confused why we're allowed to write `g x y = f y x` when we haven't declared either x or y yet. I understand that lazy evaluation means neither is evaluated until they're needed, but I expected the compiler to at least want a declaration.

It compiles even without the type signature... this works fine:

```
flip' f = g  
    where g x y = f y x
```

So are x and y just completely untyped variables? Or is something else going on? Why are we able to do this?

Comment: x and y are _polymorphically_ typed variables. They're not used in any special way, so their type can be anything.

Comment: @AndrewC thanks - that's a helpful way to think about it, and a great keyword for my further research as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm confused why we're allowed to write g x y = f y x when we haven't
>   declared either x or y yet.

Since g, x and y appear to the left of an equal sign, they are, in fact, declared. The `where` introduces a scope local to the code it is attached to. The code could be written thus:

```
flip f = let g x y = f y x in g
```

In english: Let g be a function with two arguments called x and y ....

Comment: Thanks, I think this sums it up for me: "Since g, x and y appear to the left of an equal sign, they are, in fact, declared." I think I was confused because they're on both sides of the equals sign, and usually in an imperative language you'd have trouble if you declared x using `x = x + 1`. (Depending on the language it would fail, or interpret the right x as 0 so the expression evaluates to 1, but that's still bad practice IMHO.). But once I realize that `g x y = f y x` is actually a function **definition** and `f y x` is the **body**, it looks a whole lot more reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

`where` works exactly the same as declaring a completely new function. The only difference is that function exists in local scope of function within which where was used. This means that code you provided when called is equivalent to:

```
flip' f -- Equivalent to flip' (\x y -> f x y) 
-- After we call it we have in our environment(scope) function f

g x y = f y x -- Here you call it and it is perfectly fine, because f is defined
```

What about types? Compiler tries to deduce types for `g` based on information it has. The information it has is that type of `g` must be the same as `f` except for flipped order of arguments, it also notices that f has only two arguments. So type deduction algorithm in general says that if `f :: a -> b -> c` then `g :: b -> a -> c`.

Comment: I just want to add that technically you can specify the type explicitly for a function in ``where`` block; it is just not done that often because these functions are small and an explicit type declaration only adds to confusion (and the signature is usually obvious from the types of the external function).

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the helpful comments about type deduction and scope. I am a little confused by your example, if we just do `flip' f` and then `g x y = f y x` how does the body of `flip'` ever get defined? (Part of the problem may be that I don't yet grok the meaning of slashes as in `flip' (\x y -> f x y)`... haven't gotten that far in my studies yet)

Comment: @Bogdan thanks for that point, makes it even clearer that it's just a function definition. That's what I was missing the first time.

Comment: @Stephen I meant, that `flip' f` is not definition but calling function which is defined in your snippets. Later I just explain what is in scope when the call is made.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special with the second examples. Also in the first example, the type signature is optional, so the following line works on its own:

```
flip'' f y x = f x y
```

In Haskell, you don't have to specify the types of variables, but the Haskell implementation can infer them for you. You can use `:t flip''` in ghci to check that the inferred type of `flip''` is what you would expect.

So can you use variables without declarations or without type in Haskell? No. You can only use variables that are bound somewhere, for example, because they occur to the left of an `=` sign in an equation. And every variable has to have a type, even if it is a polymorphic type variable like `a`, `b`, and `c` in the question. It is just that the programmer doesn't have to declare the type to the Haskell implementation, but the Haskell implementation can figure the type out based on the how the variable is used.

Note that this "figuring the type out" business is still *static typing*. The Haskell implementation first figures out the type of all variables, and then the program is compiled or run. So if there is a type error, you get an error message before the program even starts running.

Comment: Thanks for making it explicit that variables are still bound and have types (even if they are polymorphic types), that's what I was unsure about. And that's a very pertinent reminder that it's still static typing, i.e. polymorphism doesn't imply dynamic typing.